# How to prevent the pop-up of pdf file after the LaTex codes being compiled?

Tags: c#, winforms, latex

I am making a WinForm application with C#, in which I will compile some LaTex codes and get the resulting PDF file and then I will convert the PDF file to an image. **But every time  I cilck the button, the PDF file pops up**, that's quite annoying! The following are my codes related to that button.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                              
            p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = "F:\\texlive\\2018\\bin\\win32\\pdflatex";                
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "input.tex";// input.tex is the latex file I prepared
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;               
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p1.Start();
           // richTextBox2.Text = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();   
            pdfWrapper.LoadPDF("output.pdf"); // use PdfLiNnet to convert the output pdf file to jpg
            pdfWrapper.ExportJpg("output.jpg",1,1,  Dpi, Qua);                             
            p1.WaitForExit();               
            p1.Close();
        }
```

Does anyone know how to prevent or hide the pop-up of pdf file after the LaTex codes being compiled? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running pdflatex.exe from the command line with the /? switch? or is pdfWrapper.LoadPDF loading the PDF? Try removing the conversion to jpg part and see if it still pops up. It could be that LoadPDF is causing it to display. You'll then need to look into the "pdfWrapper" code to see how to not show it.

Comment: I have tried it. It still pops up. Emm...I may give it up...@HandbagCrab